# Как сделать автоматический переход по видео файлам

Tags: javascript, css

Ребят , есть видео слайдер  с миниатюрами и с 4 видео файлами , как сделать автоматический переход по видео после завершения видео

Html

```
  <div id="slider">
            <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" checked="">
            <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
            <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
            <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">

            <div id="slides">
                <div id="overflow">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="page">
                            <video src="videos/1.mp4" class="vidos" preload="metadata"  controls></video>
                        </div>
                        <div class="page">
                            <img src="images/4.gif"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="page">
                            <video src="videos/3.mp4" class="vidos" preload="metadata"  controls></video>
                        </div>
                        <div class="page">
                            <video src="videos/2.mp4" class="vidos" preload="metadata"   controls></video>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--inner-->
                </div> <!--overflow-->
            </div> <!--slides-->

            <div id="active">
                <label for="slide1">
                    <video src="videos/1.mp4"></video>
                </label>
                <label for="slide2">
                    <img src="images/2.jpg"/>
                </label>
                <label for="slide3">
                    <video src="videos/3.mp4"></video>
                </label>
                <label for="slide4">
                    <video src="videos/2.mp4"></video>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
var labels = document.querySelectorAll('#active label');
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .page > *');
var imgLink = document.getElementById('img_link');
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('#slides video');
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('winclose');
var openBtn = document.querySelector('.button-image');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(el, i) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var index = this.getAttribute('for').replace('slide', '');
        var curVid = slides[index - 1];

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(slides, function(el, i) {
            if (el.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
                el.pause();
                el.currentTime = 0;
            }
            imgLink.style.display = 'none';
        });

        if (curVid.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
            curVid.play();
        } else {
            imgLink.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
});

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(videos, function(el, i) {
        el.pause();
        el.currentTime = 0;
    });
});

openBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var labels = document.querySelectorAll('#active label');
    labels[0].click();
    videos[0].play();
});
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler(e) {
    document.getElementById('video').src = 'resources/2.mov';
    document.getElementById('video').play();
}
```